# How to disable Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteEndPoint.InvokeAsync?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, ide

Quite often my Visual Studio seems to become really sluggish after a while. It is like typing in mud. I have been lucky that last time I had this I got actually a relevant crash and a stacktrace showing after I closed a process:

```
StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException : The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before 
the request could complete.
    at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
    at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteEndPoint.InvokeAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
```

As far as I know I have already disabled all "Live analysis" in all my projects:

[image: Live analysis disabled]

Where is this still coming from? How important is it? How can I disable this as much as possible.

Poor typing performance is one of the most frustrating parts of VS.

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/675293/feature-xxx-is-currently-unavailable-due-to-an-int?page=1#answers) discussion on ms forum seems to address this issue.